# How to append an extension to GetFileName?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012, msdn

I'm trying to save a file using IFileSaveDialog. However, when the dialog box appears and I enter the desired file name, choose the extension from the drop down and click save it returns me the path to the file without the extension.
So my question is how to make the IFileSaveDialog automatically add an extension to the end of the file name? without having to force the user to manually enter the extension as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `SetDefaultExtension()` before showing your dialog box.

Comment: This is the correct answer, albeit short.  A common mistake is to call it with the string that uses a leading ".", don't.

Comment: Hans, thanks for your reply. Though I've read the documentation thoroughly and didn't write the extension with the dot. It still doesn't let me to save it with the default extension in place.

Comment: This answer is correct. It didn't append the extension to the filname, because I was calling `SetDefaultExtension()` after `SetFileTypes()`. Hence, changing the order fixed the problem